# How to escape $_GET and check if isset?

Tags: sanitization

I submitted a plugin to wordpress and I got a feedback that I have to escape this one
`$active_tab = isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'tab' ] : 'front_page_options';`

If I do like

`$get_the_param = esc_html($_GET[ 'tab' ] );`

`$active_tab = isset( $get_the_param  ) ? $get_the_param  : 'front_page_options';`

Seems to work but as isset ( Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression )
as $_GET is not set it will throw a notice? What can be the possible solution?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really a Wordpress question it's a PHP question. Maybe you're looking for the PHP function `empty()` instead of `isset()` to check if `$_GET['tab']` had anything in it?

Comment: @mozboz `esc_html($_GET[ 'tab' ] );` this will throw error even before that

Comment: so you need to use empty, or isset or something similar before you do that then?

Comment: @mozboz Do you think this needs escaping?

Comment: Sanitising inputs is a very good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do that is using [`filter_input()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php). Here is an example for using a custom sanitize function:

```
$tab = filter_input(
    INPUT_GET, 
    'tab', 
    FILTER_CALLBACK, 
    ['options' => 'esc_html']
);

$tab = $tab ?: 'front_page_options';
```

Comment: Thank you very much!